# Running "flutter pub get" in 'projectname' Error on line 1, column 1 exit code 65

Tags: flutter

```
flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in datingo...                         
Error on line 1, column 1 of C:\sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_web_plugins\pubspec.yaml:
 Unexpected character.
  ╷
1 │   │ ^
  ╵
pub get failed (65;   ╵)
exit code 65
```

facing this error when running pub get :
my project level pubspec:

```
name: 'project name'
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.7+8

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.6
  bot_toast: ^4.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.1.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.5
  http: ^0.13.3
  logger: ^1.0.0
  lottie: ^1.1.0
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.2
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  unity_ads_plugin: ^0.2.3
  video_player: ^2.1.12
  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:  
  uses-material-design: true
```

when i build my project showing error:

```
Error on line 1, column 1 of C:\sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_web_plugins\pubspec.yaml: Unexpected character.
  ╷
1 │ 
  │ ^
  ╵
Running "flutter pub get" in datingo...                                 
pub get failed (65;   ╵)
```

Comment: Just wondering,
Did you tried without space in the project name? e.g. ```name: project_name```

Comment: Yes I also think that this error might be occurring due to the space in your project name.

Flutter does not allow us to name the project with a space in it or any other special character except underscore (_)

Comment: i delete my flutter sdk then i install it again then this problem fixed!